# Why ngx-bootstrap is not being applied on buttons that I have bin classed

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, stackblitz

See my code in stackblitz

Btn them is not applying though I have added ngx-bootstrap as dependency in stackblitz code.
See my code here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-model-example

Actually, I want to learn ngx-bootstrap model and other fundamental so to quickly check I am directly building code online in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include bootstrap styles as ngx-bootstrap documentation [states](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#installation-instructions):

You will need bootstrap styles (Bootstrap 3)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or Bootstrap 4

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-model-example-krucgb?file=src%2Findex.html)**

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yes correct. I forgot to add link in index page. One more question if you can help. If I don't add that and just setTheme from ngx-bootstrap/utils. Is it fine?

Comment: I guess it is only for resolving conflicts with bootstrap framework in other libraries or with your customized version. You still have to include bootstrap styles in your app